# How to revert the deletion operation for a submodule

Tags: git, github

How do I rollback the deleted git submodule of my REPO.
I don't mind to do force push to resolve this.
However, this could not even be done by `git checkout master lib/xxxx`
Any idea? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the commit that removed it. This is the cleanest method if you pushed out your changes.
`git revert <sha_of_removal>`

If you didn't push out your changes yet you can rebase.
`git rebase -i <sha_before_removal>`
Then remove offending commit from list.

Readd submodule
`git submodule add lib/foobar PATH_TO_FOOBAR`